# Check if a table exists in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, rails-migrations

I have a rake task that won't work unless a table exists. I'm working with more than 20 engineers on a website so I want to make sure they have migrated the table before they can do a rake task which will populate that respective table.

Does AR have a method such as `Table.exists`? How can I make sure they have migrated the table successfully?

Comment: The joke goes.. how many engineers does it take to migrate a table :)

Comment: On production 1. On Staging dozens and multiple times each .

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier just run the migrations on the start of your rake task? So you don't have to worry about missing tables.

Comment: @raskhadafi : Note that missing tables are going to give you a problem if your config/initializers use them. (i.e. even `rake db:migrate` will fail.)

Answer (score 345, accepted):

In Rails 5 the [API became explicit regarding tables/views](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/21715), collectively *data sources*.

```
# Tables and views
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.data_sources
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.data_source_exists? 'kittens'

# Tables
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.table_exists? 'kittens'

# Views
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.views
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.view_exists? 'kittens'
```

In Rails 2, 3 & 4 the API is about *tables*.

```
# Listing of all tables and views
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables

# Checks for existence of kittens table/view (Kitten model)
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.table_exists? 'kittens'
```

Getting the status of migrations:

```
# Tells you all migrations run
ActiveRecord::Migrator.get_all_versions

# Tells you the current schema version
ActiveRecord::Migrator.current_version
```

If you need more APIs for migrations or metadata see:

- [ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-1-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/schema_migration.rb) 
  this is the `ActiveRecord::Base` class for the `schema_migrations` table
- [ActiveRecord::Migrator](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-1-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/migration.rb) 
  where all the action happens when migrations are run

Comment: `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.table_exist 'users'` would check for a users table.

Comment: `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.table_exists? 'kittens` would check for a Kitten table. That is unless I destroyed all kittens! `drop_table :kittens`

Comment: Thanks guys! I just used `.index_exists?('kittens', 'paws')`

Comment: This works for ActiveRecord 3.2.11  `drop_table(:hosts_users) if table_exists? :hosts_users`

Comment: `current_version` was just what I needed to disable a model method long enough to allow its migrations to run when I finally deployed it to production. Thanks!

Comment: `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.data_source_exists? 'table_name'` is the correct one now

Answer (score 64):

even if table is not exists:

model `Kitten`, expected table `kittens`
rails 3:

Kitten.table_exists? #=> false

Comment: + 1 More elegant solution. Also works if the model overrides the table name.

Comment: Confirming this works for Rails 2.3.18-lts (tested with one table present, one missing before running script/console)

Answer (score 39):

I found this out while I was trying to remove a table via a migration:

```
drop_table :kittens if (table_exists? :kittens)
ActiveRecord::Migration.drop_table :kittens if (ActiveRecord::Base.connection.table_exists? :kittens)
```

works for Rails 3.2

This simpler form will become available in Rails 5:

```
drop_table :kittens, if_exists: true
```

Reference: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/16366

And here's the Rails 5 ActiveRecord's [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/CHANGELOG.md):

> ### Introduce the :if_exists option for drop_table.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> drop_table(:posts, if_exists: true)
> ```
>
> That would execute:
>
> ```
> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS posts
> ```
>
> If the table doesn't exist, if_exists: false (the default) raises an exception whereas if_exists: true does nothing.

Comment: This will fail if the table is in fact a view, as the table will appear to exist, but DROP TABLE can not drop it.

Answer (score 14):

**Rails 5.1**

```
if ActiveRecord::Base.connection.data_source_exists? 'table_name'
   drop_table :table_name
end
```

or

```
drop_table :table_name, if_exists: true
```

Comment: table_exists still works in rails-5, but its behavior will be changing to only check tables.  As of 5.0.1 it checks views and tables.  data_source_exists keeps that behavior and table_exists will be changing to only check tables.

Comment: He is not asking to check the table on a migration, he needs to be sure that the table exists on a rake task

Answer (score 3):

The proper way to do this is Model.table_exists?

```
class Dog < ApplicationRecord
  # something
end

do_something if Dog.table_exists?
```