# 'delayed_jobs' gem not migrating on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rake, delayed-job

**Please see update at bottom**

I'm trying to use the 'delayed_jobs' gem in my project. I got everything working in my local environment, however when I moved the project to production on Heroku I was unable to 'rake db:migrate', and am not able to get my server started. Here are the steps I followed.

*Run bundle_install with 'delayed_job' and 'delayed_job_active_record' in my gem file

*I did not run 'ails generate delayed_job:active_record' as the migration file was moved to the server from when I ran 'ails generate delayed_job:active_record' in DEV

*I ran rake db:migrate and it failed with the following error, not sure how to fix. (Note: It appears that the migration is failing due to the table not existing, which is a big issue as I need to run the migration to create the table).

```
[?25l[?25hUnable to write PID file to /app/tmp/pids/delayed_job.pid
[ActiveJob] Enqueued SquareOrderCleanupJob (Job ID: c364f5c1-a3c3-401a-95a6-a567a2813942) to DelayedJob(default) at 2016-06-04 14:57:56 UTC
[ActiveJob] Mysql2::Error: Table 'heroku_fc2daea183dcdd6.delayed_jobs' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `delayed_jobs`
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 'heroku_fc2daea183dcdd6.delayed_jobs' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `delayed_jobs`
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.21/lib/mysql2/client.rb:80:in `_query'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.21/lib/mysql2/client.rb:80:in `block in query'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.21/lib/mysql2/client.rb:79:in `handle_interrupt'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.21/lib/mysql2/client.rb:79:in `query'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:305:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:473:in `block in log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:467:in `log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:305:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:231:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:312:in `execute_and_free'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:457:in `columns'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:43:in `columns'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/attributes.rb:93:in `columns'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/attributes.rb:98:in `columns_hash'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:205:in `subclass_from_attributes?'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:54:in `new'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:16:in `enqueue_job'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:12:in `enqueue'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.3/lib/active_job/queue_adapters/delayed_job_adapter.rb:22:in `enqueue_at'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.3/lib/active_job/enqueuing.rb:69:in `block in enqueue'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:115:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:115:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:553:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:503:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:503:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:496:in `block (2 levels) in around'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:341:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:341:in `block (2 levels) in simple'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.3/lib/active_job/logging.rb:14:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.3/lib/active_job/logging.rb:14:in `block (3 levels) in '
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.3/lib/active_job/logging.rb:43:in `block in tag_logger'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.3/lib/active_job/logging.rb:43:in `tag_logger'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.3/lib/active_job/logging.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in '
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:439:in `instance_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:439:in `block in make_lambda'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:340:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:340:in `block in simple'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:495:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:495:in `block in around'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:503:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:503:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `run_callbacks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.3/lib/active_job/enqueuing.rb:67:in `enqueue'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.3/lib/active_job/configured_job.rb:13:in `perform_later'
/app/config/initializers/schedule_jobs.rb:2:in `'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in '
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `block in '
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
/app/config/environment.rb:5:in `'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:457:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
Mysql2::Error: Table 'heroku_fc2daea183dcdd6.delayed_jobs' doesn't exist
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.21/lib/mysql2/client.rb:80:in `_query'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.21/lib/mysql2/client.rb:80:in `block in query'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.21/lib/mysql2/client.rb:79:in `handle_interrupt'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.21/lib/mysql2/client.rb:79:in `query'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:305:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:473:in `block in log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:467:in `log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:305:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:231:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:312:in `execute_and_free'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:457:in `columns'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:43:in `columns'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/attributes.rb:93:in `columns'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/attributes.rb:98:in `columns_hash'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:205:in `subclass_from_attributes?'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:54:in `new'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:16:in `enqueue_job'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:12:in `enqueue'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.3/lib/active_job/queue_adapters/delayed_job_adapter.rb:22:in `enqueue_at'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.3/lib/active_job/enqueuing.rb:69:in `block in enqueue'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:115:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:115:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:553:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:503:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:503:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:496:in `block (2 levels) in around'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:341:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:341:in `block (2 levels) in simple'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.3/lib/active_job/logging.rb:14:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.3/lib/active_job/logging.rb:14:in `block (3 levels) in '
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.3/lib/active_job/logging.rb:43:in `block in tag_logger'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.3/lib/active_job/logging.rb:43:in `tag_logger'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.3/lib/active_job/logging.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in '
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:439:in `instance_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:439:in `block in make_lambda'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:340:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:340:in `block in simple'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:495:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:495:in `block in around'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:503:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:503:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `run_callbacks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.3/lib/active_job/enqueuing.rb:67:in `enqueue'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.3/lib/active_job/configured_job.rb:13:in `perform_later'
/app/config/initializers/schedule_jobs.rb:2:in `'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in '
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `block in '
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
/app/config/environment.rb:5:in `'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:457:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
[?25h
```

**UPDATE**
I figured out the problem was caused by executing the following code at the initialization of my rails app. I was able to get the migration to work by temporarily removing it, and then adding it back in after the migration was complete (the code require the migration to be run before it was run). This is a temporary patch so I am going to work on getting a better solution for future PROD pushes. I'm thinking I can find a way to check if the table exists before running the code, but if anyone knows of a better way please let me know.

```
system("ruby lib/background_job start")
SquareOrderCleanupJob.set(wait: 10.minute).perform_later()
at_exit do
    system("ruby lib/background_job stop")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a table exists, and therefore if migrations have been run:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.table_exists? 'table_name'
```

That answer is also in SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6590107/check-if-a-table-exists-in-rails).